# Adding users to tenant using REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

According to this [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-multi-tenancy/#add-users) I can add users to specific tenant, is there REST API to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SCIM 2.0 API to add users.

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/using-the-scim-2.0-rest-apis/#using-the-scim-20-rest-apis